# how to detect distribution and production provisioning profile just by its file

Tags: ios, iphone

If we have a provisioning profile how can we  detect if its a production or development provisioning file. And also to get the devices add to the provisioning profile

Answer (score 1):

I have got answer to my question. Open the provisioning profile in textedit and look for Entitlements here you would get aps environment, by looking into this we can differentiate it from development or production. [Image shows difference between[Image shows the devices added in this provision profile.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFPSP.png) production and development provision file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC6Ux.png)